# Looking Away from the Temptations of the Solution Key

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

This is quite a soft question and I believe that it is a very important one and one that many self-learners can relate to.

So I recently was going through a problem set in topology and I came across two or three problems that I could not solve for about three days. As a self-learner, you really have no one to go to other than the textbook and the internet. I found a fully in-depth solution key to all the questions in the text and looked it over. I found out that the answers were simple enough and all I needed to do was interpret a lemma in a way that it can be interpreted to the question.

I told myself that I would not look at the answer key unless I *really* needed it because I wanted to answer the question by my own knowledge alone. However that did not last for long as I started to reluctantly peek at the solution key periodically. It became quite irritating and frustrating that I needed the solution to work out a problem set that I am suppose to be able to do after reading the material for it.

The problem sets are supposed to 
prove your understanding of the subject matter and I think that if I look at the solutions, I am not understanding and should not move on.

So in terms of questions:

1. When is it OK to look at the solution key?
2. Is there a way I can stray away for the solution key or learn a different way?
3. If you were a self learner, what would you do in this situation? Keep sitting on the problem until you solve it or look at the solution key, understand and move on?
4. What else should be addressed? Are there more relevant questions to ask here? Suggestions?

Feel free to add to this question with more to further tailor and enhance this problem to address everything possible.

Comment: @T.Bongers Then can I get migrated please?

Comment: @T.Bongers OK. I will do so.

Comment: You're right in saying that this is a very important question for learners. I was unfortunate, or fortunate, that most of the books I learned from didn't have answer keys. Usually I would give up on a problem and move on after a couple of hours without substantial progress. Often, returning to the problem days later, I would have some insight that allowed a breakthrough. But leaving a problem unsolved for more than a few days would always really bother me. In your situation, if I had the willpower, I'd probably want to wait a few days before looking at the solutions.

Comment: @David however time flies and by the time I see the answer and wait a few days, I still have like four other problems in the problem set.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I didn't mean I stopped solving problems altogether for a few days. I meant I stopped trying to solve the particular one that had given me trouble. Don't neglect the fact that solving problems later in a set often gives you ideas for the earlier ones.

Comment: @David So what do you suggest for writing notes on these problems even though I looked at the solutions?

Comment: Why are you writing notes? You could just write that the solution can be found in the answer key. Or you could try to encapsulate just enough of the main ideas of the proof that you could reconstruct it later if you wanted to.

Comment: @David Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know what you need the notes for, but I assume you do.

Comment: @David Sometimes I do because when I just can't quite remember something, I can refer back to it.

Comment: Why does the solution in the answer key not serve that purpose?

Comment: @David because it is not the main idea that needs to be taken away.

Comment: In that case, try to write down enough of the main ideas that you believe you'll be able to recover the proof from what you've written.

Comment: @David Understood.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can come down to the mindset you have while working on the problem. It's easy to beat yourself up for not seeing the solution immediately when you know the person who wrote the book understands it simply, just try not to see it as a reflection of your potential in mathematics. All the great mathematicians of history have their struggles and difficulties largely forgotten with time so it seems like they understood these things intuitively without much effort or time. The thing that gets me through hard problems is remembering that it isn't the ability to see problems quickly that makes you great in this field, it's your ability to remain comfortable and confident when up to your nose in the unknown. So, next time you feel daunted like you'll never get it on your own, remember you are practicing a skill which is more important than remembering mathematical facts: not losing your determination on a difficult problem.

That being said, when is it appropriate to look at the solutions? I say whenever, you feel the need. If the debate is between giving up and looking at the solution, the choice is clear. Just because you've seen a solution doesn't mean you can't ask any meaningful questions about the solution or use the solution to delve into another topic. I think a lot about how most of mathematics growing up is just remembering number facts and it's incredibly useful because it allows you to use them without having to question them. Seeing new solutions to new problems helps you tackle those problems in the future, it isn't always about have the right answer to a question right when it's asked. Looking at solutions is a good way to keep you on track and keep your interest piqued and by looking at the answers when you are emotionally invested in them you are more likely to remember them down the road anyway.

Comment: I understand your thoughts. So what should I write for my notes in terms of writing down the solutions to the problems?

Comment: It's hard to create a general rule about looking at solutions. I think you have to evaluate how the solution is going to make you feel before you check it. If you still feel capable of answering the question but haven't figured it out yet, by all means keep trying. If you know you're going to beat yourself up for not seeing something so simple, avoid the answer keys. Find hints online that don't answer the same exact question. Ultimately, do whatever is going to keep you interested and invested in solving the problem and problems like it.

Comment: There are no hints online. They are all answers and all of the answers are pretty much all the same.

Comment: Then I can certainly understand your difficulties and desire to avoid the key. If you can, don't set expectations on how long it should take you to understand the problems perfectly. Focus on the parts you are confused about but also take the time to appreciate the aspects you are improving upon. It might take going through your book way more times than you wanted but as long as you are aware of the areas you have to work on then you can be sure that at least with every attempt on a new problem you are more equipped than last time. It will definitely pay off, just learn to enjoy the ride.

Comment: Thank you! This has been helpful. :)